# No video output from motherboard. How to debug this?

Tags: troubleshooting, components

I have assembled the following system:

- Intel g530
- ASUS p8h61 m lx
- Corsair 2 GB
- WD 250 GB
- Raidmax 500w

The system turns on but I don't receive any video output on the screen.

I tried the following:

- Starting without a CMOS battery.
- Starting without RAM.
- Starting without HDD.

All the components are brand new. I don't know which component is faulty in my case, my motherboard or the processor or both?
Also, do you have other suggestions that might help  me debug this problem?

Comment: Do you have a PC speaker connected to the motherboard?  BIOS beep codes are one of the most useful things for troubleshooting when you don't have video.  Also, can you borrow a PCIe video card and test with that?

Answer (score 0):

When you pulled the RAM, does it beep like there's no RAM? No? Then probably bad motherbaord, or bad/incompatible CPU.

According to that board's [support page](http://ca.asus.com/en/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8H61M_LX/#CPUS) at Asus, you require at least BIOS version 0501 installed to use that CPU.

You'll have to figure out which BIOS is on that motherbaord already, and that may require getting another CPU that's compatible with the version that is currently on it, so that you can boot and upgrade to 0501.

Comment: The thing is that the system worked before. I haven't used it for 3-4 months. So it can't be a incompatible CPU. I'll probably have to buy a buzzer and see if it spits out some tones. Thanks!

Comment: 3-4 months old & working before is a lot different that "I assembled the following" and "all components are brand new". You may want to edit that information into your question.