# My PC runs but I don't have any video signal on the screen

Tags: video, troubleshooting

I have a similar problem described here [No video output from motherboard how to debug this?](https://superuser.com/questions/440664/no-video-output-from-motherboard-how-to-debug-this)by the user:"alistarmk" with my computer, i.e the computer runs but I don´t have any video signal on the screen.

My Motherboard is an ASUS P8H61-M LX, and the CPU is an Intel core I3.

Please if there is any solution concerning this problem just let me know. Thanks.

**Edit**

Following some remarks:
I have checked the cables,
I have also connected my monitor on my laptop to make sure that it was not a problem from the monitor.
I have also unplugged and re-plugged the RAM, and hard drive.

It seems that only the CPU's fan is running when I start the PC up, because I can not notice the hard drive working at start up. I don't have any extension graphic card, I'm using the onboard graphics socket. I have connected the speaker to get beep codes for troubleshooting but nothing came out from the box.

I don't know if it makes sense to buy an extension graphic card to test.

Comment: You'll want to redo this question, only including important information like: Make/Model of PC. Monitor connection type. Did it ever work right? Have you checked the cables? Do you see the BIOS screen? What have you tried already?  As-is, this question is way to vague and will most likely closed as such.

Comment: Can you see a faint image? It may be the inverter.

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out in the question you linked to, one of the diagnostic steps is to boot the computer without any RAM whatsoever.  Provided you have a system speaker connected, you should hear continual beeping in some regular pattern.  This will indicate the board is working to the degree that it detects that there is no RAM present.  If your motherboard is good, there is a system speaker, the processor is good, the processor is sitting in the socket properly with no bent pins, the heat sink is properly mounted over the processor, and the power supply is good, then you would hear the diagnostic beeps.  Notice, I said nothing about requiring a hard drive, or optical drive, or video card, or even having it connected to a monitor.  You are simply connecting the basics, and attempting to force the motherboard to behave in a predictable manner.

If you do not hear any beeps... then one of those things is bad/missing.  It might be a bad motherboard.  It might be a bad processor.  It might be a bad power supply.  It might be as simple as the heat sink not sitting on the processor properly.

Why would you attempt to force the motherboard to tell you that there is no RAM present?  Because you need so little in the way of components to test that, and it presents you with a very short list of things that might be bad.  Also, if you get the diagnostic beeps you expect, then you can progress forward from there.

So, that's the first thing you should do.

How do you test your power supply?  Without a PSU tester, you would need another computer to use it in, or another power supply to use in place of it, or a multimeter and a small wiring diagram showing you what wires should produce what voltage (and what two connections to short to make the PSU power on.  You CANNOT assume that since the fan kicks on, that the PSU is working the way it should.

How do you test your processor?  That's a little more specific.  You would need another motherboard/computer that you KNOW works to put the chip in.  That... or an expensive processor tester that not many people (or even repair shops) have.

How do you test the motherboard?  Again... that's pretty specific.  You would need another processor that is made for the same socket.

So... out of all those things, and how you would test whether or not they are working properly... testing for the presence of RAM is quite easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

First step is to always check the cable by using another that you know works. Then check with another screen.  Are you using the built in (onboard) video output or do you have a video card? If you have a video card remove it from system and plug video back to stock onboard video.   When the pc first starts up can you see the ASUS "splash screen" . If you cannot see the asus splash screen after trying the above methods it is safe to assume your motherboards onboard video has gone out.  you could have a new video chipset reballed to the mainboard but the board cost less than the precedure.

Comment: Here is the exact replacement board from newegg. currently has free shipping. $64.99   http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131859&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-_-pla-_-Intel+Motherboards-_-N82E16813131859&gclid=CMCbt76jr7YCFcJ7QgodTGIAeA

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this can be a graphics card chip that has stopped working. I had this on a packard bell laptop previously. Laptop was fine but onboard graphics card was shot rendering the motherboard useless.